# How to create a directory with '/' in unix?

Tags: directory, filenames, special-characters, mkdir, slash

I want to create a directory with name as below

```
A3456/90876/IN AS%90876 JI KOL
```

Comment: Want worldpeace instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847288/is-it-possible-to-use-in-a-filename

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (As others have noted, it's not possible to have "/" in filenames. However, if you tell us why you want to do this someone may be able to suggest a "work around").

Comment: `/` is more or less the one and only character which you cannot have in the filename...and the `null` character which is kindof terminating the filename

Comment: You can't do this...BUT, **in the macOS graphical file browser, "Finder," literal colons in a file or directory name are *displayed* as `/`.**  So you can type in a `/` in a file name *in the Finder,* but the way that is actually stored is a `:`.  (And, you can't type in a `:` in a file name in the Finder, and any `:` present in the actual name will be displayed by Finder as a `/`.)

Answer (score 6):

While `/` (U+002F) is the path component separator and can't be used in file names obviously, there are a few (`╱` `⟋` `⁄` `∕` `⧸` `⁄` for instance, even a combining one (`̸`)) that look very similar and that you could use instead if the intent is to confuse or fool people using the system.

For instance:

```
mkdir A3456⁄90876⁄IN
```

Now, if you just want to create a `IN` directory inside a `90876` directory inside a `A3456` directory using one single command, then it's just:

```
mkdir -p A3456/90876/IN
```

Comment: Like the greek question mark developer trolling right? ;) `Question mark (;)  
same usage as in English, but note that it looks like the English semicolon!` -  http://starecat.com/content/wp-content/uploads/replace-semicolon-with-greek-question-mark-in-your-friends-javascript-and-watch-them-pull-their-hair-out-over-the-syntax-error-evil-trolling.jpg

Comment: Beside the code-points you propose: U+2044 U+2215 U+2571 U+27CB U+29F8 you may add U+337 U+338 U+FF0F. But either your proposed chars or all of them could not be encoded in a code-page that generates zeros. An Unix filename must not include NULs. For example UTF32 use a lot of NULs. Testing all possible encoding in iconv I find that only this list GB18030 ISO-IR-193 OSF05010001 UTF7 UTF8 meet the requirements of being able of encoding all chars and also avoid the use of NUL. Any other encoding fail.

Answer (score 4):

The character `/` is not allowed to appear in file names, including directory names. It is *always* [interpreted as a separator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13) between pathname components.

Sources:

> **Pathname**
>
> A string that is used to identify a file. In the context of POSIX.1-2008, a pathname may be limited to {PATH_MAX} bytes, including the terminating null byte. It has optional beginning <slash> characters, followed by zero or more filenames separated by <slash> characters. A pathname can optionally contain one or more trailing <slash> characters. Multiple successive <slash> characters are considered to be the same as one <slash>, except for the case of exactly two leading <slash> characters.
>
> Note:
>
> If a pathname consists of only bytes corresponding to characters from the portable filename character set (see Portable Filename Character Set), <slash> characters, and a single terminating <NUL> character, the pathname will be usable as a character string in all supported locales; otherwise, the pathname might only be a string (rather than a character string). Additionally, since the single-byte encoding of the <slash> character is required to be the same across all locales and to not occur within a multi-byte character, references to a <slash> character within a pathname are well-defined even when the pathname is not a character string. However, this property does not necessarily hold for the remaining characters within the portable filename character set.
>
> Pathname Resolution is defined in detail in [*Pathname Resolution*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13).
>
> (*The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7*, volume *Base Definitions*, chapter 3 "Definitions", *s.v.* 3.271 [Pathname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271))

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  It's explicitly prohibited per [the POSIX definition of a path/file name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_170):

> **3.170 Filename**
>
> A sequence of bytes consisting of 1 to {NAME_MAX} bytes used to name a
>   file. **The bytes composing the name shall not contain the `<NUL>` or
>   `<slash>` characters**. In the context of a pathname, each filename shall
>   be followed by a `<slash>` or a `<NUL>` character; elsewhere, a filename
>   followed by a `<NUL>` character forms a string (but not necessarily a
>   character string). The filenames dot and dot-dot have special meaning.
>   A filename is sometimes referred to as a "pathname component". See
>   also Pathname

Comment: Now I understand why gradle uses `:`